# Need to execute multiple commands on Runtime.getRunTime().exec

Tags: android, runtime.exec

```
public void uninstallApp(String packageName){
       try {

                String[] command = new String[4];
                command[0] = "su";
                command[1] = "mount -o remount,rw /system";
                command[2] = "rm " + packageName;
                command[3] = "reboot";
                Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
                run.exec(command);

                Log.d("DELETED", packageName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("ERROR ON DELETE", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

That's my code. This method receives an apk's path, what i need to do is execute those commands but without loosing permissions. I mean, if i execute "su" in one process and then "mount" in other process. "mount" won't have "su" access. So i need to execute all those commands in a single process. And that's not working. :\

Comment: Please indent your code properly. You seem to have a spurious `}` before the `catch`. Please make sure that your posted code is valid.

Comment: Can you define "not working" in this case?

Comment: The array you pass to exec() is not multiple commands, it's one command and it's command line parameters.

Comment: Oh i fixed the extra } . But it wasnt the problem. When i say "it doesnt work" i mean it doesnt execute anything. ci_ You said the array is not multiple commands. How should i execute multiple commands?

Comment: Check the man page for su, it can take a -c parameter to execute a command as another user.

Comment: Yep I've seen that but didn't work. I'll tell you why.
When i executed "su -c mount -o remount,rw /system" it returned "Permission denied" Because the "su" wasn't giving me access (dont know why) and if i used more than 2 commands like :
"su -c mount -o remount,rw /system -c reboot"
It didn't work at all u.u. But if i run the same code from an Android terminal it works perfectly

Comment: @ci_ the `su` in question *does not have a man page*.  Some implementation can take command line arguments, other cannot.

Comment: @ChrisStratton 
 
So, there is no way to execute multiple commands on same process? :|

Comment: The usual approach is to pipe them into the process's stdin.  It's been covered here many times before, but wasn't finding an outstanding example to duplicate close against.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: I Found a solution looking for ProcessBuilder Thank you @AndrewThompson and thanks everybody for feedback!

Comment: You should not put your solution into the question. Could you please put your solution into an answer? This would help us to maintain the Q&A format on SO.

Answer (score 1):

**FOUND SOLUTION**

```
StringBuilder cmdReturn = new StringBuilder();

try {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("su","-c mount -o remount,rw /system ; rm " + packageName + " ; reboot");
    Process process = processBuilder.start();

    InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
    int c;
    while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        cmdReturn.append((char) c);
    }

    Log.d("CMD RESPONSE", cmdReturn.toString());

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ProcessBuilder pattern. just add your commands to the String array in order:

`Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", command1, command2});`